# Android OpenGL OutOfMemory (Allocating buffers)

Tags: android, opengl-es, buffer, out-of-memory

I'm parsing a binary file with vertices and their properties. These files range from 50,000-2,000,000 vertices. For the lower files, I have no problems allocating straight off of arrays and drawing the points, but for larger files, its a big problem.

When I create a floatbuffer as such:

```
FloatBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
```

I sometimes get **OutOfMemory** errors. This isn't the only buffer I draw, I also do color. Is there a better way of drawing the vertices or allocating on the fly to the buffers and I draw everytime? Here is some basic drawing code I am using:

```
public PointCloud(String passedFileName, Context ctx) {

    fileName = passedFileName;
    header = new LAS_HeadParser(fileName);
    numVertices = (int)header.numberOfPoints;

    lasVertices = new float[numVertices*3];
    lasColors = new float[numVertices*4];
    intensity = new float[numVertices];
    vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(lasVertices.length * 4);
    cbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(lasColors.length * 4);

    new ProgressTask(ctx).execute();
}
public void setupBuffers(){
    // a float is 4 bytes, therefore we multiply the number if 
    // vertices with 4.

    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(lasVertices);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);   

    cbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    colorBuffer = cbb.asFloatBuffer();
    colorBuffer.put(lasColors);
    colorBuffer.position(0);
}

public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    //Log.d("Enter Draw", "*****************");
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, colorBuffer);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glPointSize(0.6f);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_POINTS, 0, numVertices);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

The call `new ProgressTask(ctx).execute();` just parses and populates arrays. I can't afford to continually parse the file, it takes too long. What options do I have?

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the OutOfMemory error?

Comment: @DoomGoober - vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(lasVertices.length * 4);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I don't know what you're rendering, but it seems rather odd to render 50,000 GL_POINTs. If you were to render polys instead (using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP or GL_TRIANGLE_FAN) you can cut the number of vertices probably in half or even in third, depending on how well you optimize the data.

2) You may be holding two references to the vertex and color buffers. According to documentation allocateDiret MAY map to intermediate memory -- or it may just copy the whole byte[]. Let the garbage collector clean up lasVertices and lasColors by making them local variables in the PointCloud constructor, rather than having them be member variables. (Or if they have to be members, set them to null after putting them in the ByteBuffers.) That way, if ByteBuffer is copying the data, you won't have two copies.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understand your thoughts on the # of points, however it is necessary. Also, this is not supposed to be rendered with shapes (and if it were, wouldn't I have yet another array of indices?). Can I increase Android's avaliable app memory somehow? Thanks again!

Comment: Your code has 3 temporary buffers and 2 buffers actually needed for rendering. First, if you can, kill the extra unused buffer called intensity. Next, if possible, rearrange your code like so: allocate temporary, copy temporary into ByteBuffer. "Release" temporary. Allocate next temporary, copy temporary into ByteBuffer. "Release" temporary. Render ByteBuffers. At most, you should only have N + 1 buffers in memory, where N is the number of buffers required for a render call. Currently, you have N + 2 buffers in memory (assuming intensity is not used.)

Comment: BTW, when I say release, I mean "remove references to the buffers so the garbage collector can clean them up." I'm not super familiar with Java's garbage collector, but I assume it runs on allocate with not enough memory. Something like lasVertices = null should do the trick, assuming you have no other references to that byte array.

Comment: Intensity will be used, because I will swap the rendering between color and intensity of each vertex (haven't gotten to that switch yet, but still need the data). The only way I can cut down the order of buffers would be to parse for one array, store it. parse for a second, store it... etc. The parsing can take a while on some of these, it isn't something I want to consider. I have however thrown in the ability to only grab every (n)'th vertex, so grabbing 1/4th of the points from the file is possible, but still... What about storing the arrays on an SD card and going from there?

Comment: Could you write vertex data directly to ByteBuffers using putFloat instead of allocating temporary float arrays? ByteBuffer writes are slower than float arrays, but it'll cut down on your max memory usage (max memory will be three buffers, versus your current five, assuming allocateDirect is actually allocating buffers rather than using an array backed methodology.)

Comment: This won't work. Apparently I need to allocate them before writing to them :(